# Most efficient way to implement blog tags in a relational database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, tags, blogs

I am using ASP.NET MVC5, Entity Framework, Web API 2, OData, MSSQL backend; a pretty standard MS stack I suppose... and wondering: What's the best setup / structure for a **simple** blog system with regards to "Tags"? Should I store each tag in a Tags table as a new row? Or is there a better / more efficient way? It might be worth mentioning that I may also wish to use tags in other parts of my site later (perhaps in the CMS pages I have and so forth)... so I need to think of the best way to make this efficient and extensible.

Comment: I don't know about the most efficient way, but you definitly should not use `GUID` as **PK** of your tags table. Couse it will lead to really heavy joins later.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple table for tags:

```
TblTags 
-------
TagId int (pk, identity)
TagName varchar(30) (unique, or nvarchar, and use whatever length that suits your needs.)
```

Then use an intersection table with tags and whatever, for example blog articles:

```
TblTagsToBlogArticle
--------------------
TTBA_BlogArticle_Id
TTBA_Tag_Id
```

Note that the primary key should contain both columns of this table.

Comment: Thank you Zohar for taking the time to answer. However, this is exactly what I was referring to in my original question. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way, but I suppose the answer is likely to be no. Anyway, thanks for trying.  :-)

Comment: AFAIK, in a relational database there is no better way